# Searching for string input using a function bool deleteAcc(const string name1) in doubly linkedlist in C++98?

Tags: search, boolean, doubly-linked-list, c++98

All my other functions of my doubly linked list which consist of Account class and Node class are all working except this last function.

The function bool deleteAcc(string name) will take as it’s argument, the string name (that the user inputs) and returns a bool result. It will then find the name in the list and delete the corresponding Account (and Node) from the list, then return True. If the Account was not in the list, it will return False.

This is my code as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include <string>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

bool deleteAcc(const string name1);

int main(){

    string name;
    int k;
    cout << "How many accounts do you want to enter? ";
    cin >> k;

    Node* head = NULL;
    //Node* tail = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        string name;
        double balance;

        cout << "Enter account name: ";
        cin >> name;

        cout << "Enter account balance: ";
        cin >> balance;
    
        Account account(name, balance);

        Node* newNode = new Node(account);

        if (head == NULL) {
            // The list is empty, so set both head and tail to the       
            // new node
            head = newNode;
            // tail = newNode;
        } else {
            // The list is not empty, so add the new node to the  
            // tail
            newNode->setNext(head);
            //newNode->setPrevious(head); // Update previous pointer 
            // of newNode to point to the previous last node (i.e.,   
            // tail)
            head = newNode;
        }
    }

    // Print the list
    cout << "Account balances:" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    Node* currentNode = head;

    while (currentNode != NULL) {
        cout << currentNode->getData() << endl;
        currentNode = currentNode->getNext();
    }

    cout << "Enter the account name you want to delete: ";
    cin >> name;
    deleteAcc(name);



    // Deallocate memory
    currentNode = head;

    while (currentNode != NULL) {
        Node* nextNode = currentNode->getNext();
        delete currentNode;
        currentNode = nextNode;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool deleteAcc(const string name1)
{
    Node* currentNode = head;
    Node* previousNode = NULL;

    while (currentNode != NULL){
        if (currentNode->getData().getName() == name1) {
            if (previousNode == NULL) {
                // The node to be deleted is the head node
                head = currentNode->getNext();
            }   
            else {
            // The node to be deleted is in the middle of the list
            previousNode->setNext(currentNode->getNext());
            }  

        delete currentNode;
        return true;
        }

        // Update the previous node and move to the next node
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->getNext();
    }

    // The account was not found in the list
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that head inside the deleteAcc(name) function is outside of the scope so is it even possible to answer this question with just a single argument string inside the bool deleteAccount(string name)????

Please help. Thanks

I have tried many times to find how to solve this problem like declaring head at the top of the file before int main() like this:

```
Node* head = NULL; 

int main(){
    // functions and variables here
}
```

but it does not produce the desired result of showing an output.

Comment: Why do you define `head` as a global variable? What does `currentNode->getData()` return, and is it printable?

Comment: @trincot, because the compiler keeps complaining that head was our of scope when I used my function bool deleteAcc(const string name1) which is defined outside of the int main(). so that is why I defined it as a global variable. but I think that is why it does not produce an output. currentNode->getData() return (name, balance) as stored in Account object and yes it is printable.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, in addition to having a `Node` class/struct, you'd also have another class/struct to represent the doubly linked list, and that class would  hold the `head` node, as well as any other functions relevant to the list. See this example:

```
class Dllist {
    private:
        Node *head;
        int size;
    public:
        bool insertAcc(const string &name1);
        bool deleteAcc(const string &name1);
        Node *findAcc(const string &name1);
        // ...
};
```

Then, your `deleteAcc` function (as well as any other function defined as part of `Dllist`) would have access to `head`.

As you've written the code now, I'm inferring from this comment that you've set up the list entirely within `main`: `// other functions and variables written here`. If that's the case, then the only way that you'd have access to `head` without adding an additional parameter to the `deleteAcc` function would be to make `head` a global variable, which I'd strongly discourage.

On another node, your title has the phrase "doubly linked list", but it looks like your `deleteAcc` function is only modifying the forward link (i.e. calling `->setNext`. For the list to maintain its status as a doubly linked list, you need to make sure that both the forward and backwards links are set appropriately.

**Update:** I'm responding to your comment here because the formatting is better:

> @fireshawdow52, I have edited my code and put all of my code in my post. Also, it is a doubly linked list but the previous question before this, tell us to reverse order the printout of the list so I came to that conclusion that tail will not be needed anymore because it is causing compilation error.

Your `tail` member is absolutely needed for the structure to be doubly linked. However, `newNode->setPrevious(head)` won't work, as that'll result in both `getNext()` and `getPrevious()` returning the same `Node`. You'll want `head->setPrevious(newNode)` after the call to `newNode->setNext(head)`. The reason has to do with how you're constructing your list.

Consider that we want to add three `Account`s, and they'll be named "Account 1", "Account 2", and "Account 3". Here is how your list will look after the addition of each account.

**After adding Account 1**

```
     head
      |
      v
|           |
| Account 1 |
|           |
```

**After adding Account 2**

```
     head
      |
      v
|           |      |           |
| Account 2 | ---> | Account 1 |
|           |      |           |
```

**After adding Account 3**

```
     head
      |
      v
|           |      |           |      |           |
| Account 3 | ---> | Account 2 | ---> | Account 1 |
|           |      |           |      |           |
```

Given the above, if you uncomment the line `newNode->setPrevious(head)`, then your final list will look like this, with each node having two pointers pointing to the same node, which is not how a doubly linked list should be set up:

```
     head ____________     ____________________
      |   |           |    |                  |
      v   |           v    |                  v
|         | |      |       |   |      |           |
| Account 3 | ---> | Account 2 | ---> | Account 1 |
|           |      |           |      |           |
```

With `head->setPrevious(newNode)`, then you ultimately get:

```
     head
      |
      v
|           |      |           |      |           |
| Account 3 | ---> | Account 2 | ---> | Account 1 |
|           | <--- |           | <--- |           |
```

This is because, for instance, when you set the `next` pointer for "Account 2", `head` is still "Account 1", and adding a `previous` pointer to that node is the inverse of `newNode->setNext(head)`.

Comment: @fireshawdow52, I have edited my code and put all of my code in my post. Also, it is a doubly linked list but the previous question before this, tell us to reverse order the printout of the list so I came to that conclusion that tail will not be needed anymore because it is causing compilation error.